# I can't see data from database (supplied argument is not a valid)

Tags: php, mysql

I can't understand why i get supplied argument is not a valid?
My codes belove

dbconnect.class.php http://ideone.com/AILC9

getdata.class.php   http://ideone.com/wIbL3

header.class.php http://ideone.com/OQSg9

index.php
http://ideone.com/Zp6sF

When I run index.php I can get this codes:

```
<html>

 <head>

  <title>   <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\getdata.class.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
  </title>

  <meta name="description" content="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\getdata.class.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
" />

  <meta name="keywords" content="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\getdata.class.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
" />

 </head>

</html>
```

Comment: You most probably have an error in your sql syntax. What does `mysql_error` say?

Comment: I paste my code to sql runner of phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin returns true data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is failing with your mysql connection/query. `echo mysql_error()` after each call to header to reveal the errors.

Also in your `sayfaHeader()` method, the last 2 lines will never be executed because you have 2 returns, once you `return` function execution ends.

Comment: I can't understand anything :)

Comment: @Birlikisgu then I suggest you ask a community in a language you understand or use Google Translate!

Answer (score 0):

In your database connection class you are not checking whether the connection itself was made. This error indicates that a valid mysql connection was not made so there's no resource attached to that variable. You may not get an error so you should always exit/die if your connection == null. Make sure your database credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this

```
protected function getData()
{
    $result = mysql_query($this->sql, $this->database) or $this->error = mysql_error();
    if($result !== false) die(mysql_error());

    while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $this->data[] = $rs;
    }
    $dataObject = (object) $this->data;
    return (array) $this->data;
}
```

it will return an error that will tell you what's wrong with your query